# PHP Code on One Line

Tags: php

I remember years ago when I was first learning PHP that there were some circumstances where PHP code could be kept to a single line, but I can't recall what the rules were.

Here's an example that I'm wondering if I can keep on line line for readability purposes as it's mixed with a lot of HTML table code:

```
<?php if ($contact->getField('nameLast') !='') {
echo ' & <br /> '.$contact->getField('nameLast') ;
}  ?>
```

Is it possible to have that remain all on a single line like this:

```
<?php if ($contact->getField('nameLast') !='') {echo ' & <br /> '.$contact->getField('nameLast') ; }  ?>
```

Comment: `($contact->getField('nameLast') != '') ? $contact->getField('nameLast') : ''` ?

Comment: [Ternary Operators.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) - (`echo ($contact->getField('nameLast') !='') ? ' & <br /> '.$contact->getField('nameLast') : '';`)

Comment: Maybe I can make this my answer. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try don't know whether it would work or not. Its called **Ternary Operator**. Google Ternary Operator PHP

```
<?php if ($contact->getField('nameLast') !='') {
echo ' & <br /> '.$contact->getField('nameLast') ;
}  ?>
```

to this

```
echo ($contact->getField('nameLast') !='')?' & <br /> '.$contact->getField('nameLast'):"";
```